# How can I highlight the points lying between two lines in a ListPlot?

Tags: plotting

I have a list of numbers like the following:

```
list = Table[RandomInteger[1000], {i, 1000}];
```

And I plot them so:

```
ListPlot[list]
```

[image]

I have drawn the black lines on the plot myself. I'd like to have `min` and `max` variables as a function of `y`, which once set, produce these lines in the chart and highlight the data between the lines. How can I do this?

Comment: No, I want the area between these two lines get highlighted with a color e.g light yellow so that I can understand the density of this range easily

Comment: Please clarify your question as to whether the `min` and `max` variables mentioned are constants of the form `y_min ` and `y_max `,  the slopes of lines through the origin, or possibly more complex functions that will plot as curves on the data plot.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I've updated the chart with what I mean. By specified sections I mean in a given range what percent of data lies between lies and how  can show these values on the chart?

Comment: @MohsenAfshin I suggest you ask that as a new question, as its focus is entirely different from this one. In future, please do not move the goal posts after people have taken the effort to answer the question. It's probably ok if they're very closely related, but in this case, they're not.

Comment: @Hypnotoad, I appreciated your note and revert the question back to the original one. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I shall suppose that you want something like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The first step is to convert your data into the **(x, y)** specified form:

```
list = RandomReal[2, 1000];
list = MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, list];
```

Then define bound functions:

```
low  = 0.5 + Sin[#/150`]/4 &;
high = 1.2 + Sin[#/100`]/3 &;
```

Gather points according to these functions:

```
list2 = Sort @ GatherBy[list, low@# < #2 < high@# & @@ # &];
```

Plot the points and functions and display together with `Show`:

```
Show[
 ListPlot[list2, PlotStyle -> {Red, Black}],
 Plot[{low@x, high@x}, {x, 0, 1000}]
]
```

Comment: When I change low and high to low = # &;
high = 3 # &; it doesn't work, why?

Comment: @Mohsen It works just as it should but those bound functions make no sense for this data.  Try `low = #/300 &; high = #/100 &;` instead.

Comment: I prefer this syntax `list2 = Sort@GatherBy[list, (low[#[[1]]] < #[[2]] < high[#[[1]]]) &];`

Comment: @Murta that works too but I have Bracket Phobia so I like mine better. :^)

Comment: huahuahua.. Bracket Phobia is good.. :-) . Using Esc [[ Esc it's not so ugly, but ok!.. In your honor follows improved version `list2 = Sort@GatherBy[list, low@#[[1]] < #[[2]] < high@#[[1]] &]`

Comment: @Mohsen I see you Accepted my answer.  Thank you.  Please note that the `Sort` I used may be unstable in your application.  As written it simply sorts the points gathered by how many there are; that is, the area with the fewer points will be colored red, but if the area to be highlighted actually has more points in it than not it will flip.  You may want to use something like `SortBy[(* gather *), #[[1, 2]]&]` instead.  Should you have any trouble with this please ask and I'll assist.

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Wizard, don't have you any solution to the Updated section of the question?

Comment: @Mohsen Sorry, I didn't see that until now.  I'm about to sleep though, so I'll take a look tomorrow.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this :

-- Edit by MA ---

```
min[n_, minPercent_] = minPercent* n;
max[n_, maxPercent_] = maxPercent* n;

SeedRandom[6];
list = Table[RandomInteger[1000], {i, 1000}];

Manipulate[
 ListPlot[{list, min[#, minPercent] & /@ Range[1000], 
   max[#, maxPercent] & /@ Range[1000]}, 
  Filling -> {3 -> {2}}],
 {minPercent, 0.0, 5.0}, {maxPercent, 0.0, 5.0}]
```

[image]

Comment: How can I convert this to a demonstration so that by changing the sliders of min and max the chart changes?

Comment: You can use `Manipulate` and change the slopes and intercepts (or more generally the curves) for `min, max`. Give it a try and come back if you get stuck.

Comment: The performance of the chart is a little slow when I change the minPercent and maxPercent. Can it be optimized?

Answer (score 5):

A comment on performance...

The `Manipulate` in the answer works smoothly and promptly on my old iMac (which does have 12GB memory), so it's not easy to detect improvements in performance.

There are many techniques for optimizing dynamic interfaces in *Mathematica*, and so far I've learnt a couple.

First, switch off continuous updating:

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[
  {list, min[#, minPercent] & /@ Range[1000], 
   max[#, maxPercent] & /@ Range[1000]},
  Filling -> {3 -> {2}}],
 {minPercent, 0.0, 5.0, ContinuousAction -> False},
 {maxPercent, 0.0, 5.0, ContinuousAction -> False}]
```

This updates the display only when you release the slider.

A more interesting way is to use `ControlActive` and provide alternative displays for when a control is active:

```
Manipulate[
 ControlActive[
  ListPlot[{min[#, minPercent] & /@ Range[1000], 
    max[#, maxPercent] & /@ Range[1000]}, 
   Filling -> {2 -> {1}}],
  ListPlot[{list, min[#, minPercent] & /@ Range[1000], 
    max[#, maxPercent] & /@ Range[1000]},
   Filling -> {3 -> {2}}]],
 {minPercent, 0.0, 5.0},
 {maxPercent, 0.0, 5.0}]
```

The `list` is plotted only when you stop moving the sliders.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using a very poor computer, and I'm also getting some poor performance. The following helps a lot (Note that I'm  picking up from b.gatessucks so evaluate his functions first):

```
Manipulate[Show[
   plot,
   Plot[{max[x, maxPercent], min[x, minPercent]}, {x, 1, 1000}, 
       Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]],
{minPercent, 0.0, 5.0}, {maxPercent, 0.0, 5.0},
Initialization :> {plot = ListPlot[list]}]
```

That way, you only have to plot the thousand points once.

Comment: Perfect performance, just why?

Comment: @MohsenAfshin. Because this `Manipulate` only contructs the ListPlot graphic once in the initialization phase and not over and over again at each update.

Comment: @MohsenAfshin In addition to what m_goldberg described about not having to re-plot the points at every update, using `Plot` rather than `ListPlot` and lots of points to draw lines happens to be more efficient. This is because MMA's optimized `Plot` function just samples 157 points in this case, whereas `ListPlot` forces it to find and display all 1000 points.