# How to find all data points within closed curve

Tags: geometry

I want to find all data points inside curve as given below:

```
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {200, 2}];
ParametricPlot[{Sin[u], Sin[2 u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Point[data]}]
```

Short solution is preferable

Thanks.

Comment: Related but simpler question: [(17306)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17306)

Comment: Also related: [How to compile Heike's winding number function?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28546/245)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using the answer by rm-f [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9417/245), you can discretized the curve into a polygon and get the desired points to any arbitrary accuracy:

```
inPolyQ[poly_, pt_] := Graphics`Mesh`PointWindingNumber[poly, pt] =!= 0

pp = Table[{Sin[u], Sin[2 u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/100}];

inPoints = Select[data, inPolyQ[pp, #] &];

ParametricPlot[{Sin[u], Sin[2 u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Point[inPoints]}]
```

[image: points inside]

**Edit for version 10**

In *Mathemtica* version 10, the problem of finding points inside a **closed curve** doesn't have to be reduced to the problem of finding points inside a `Polygon` obtained from that curve by discretization. *Instead*, you can use the following symbolic approach which requires only that the curve be specified in a suitable form that can be handled by the new `Region...` commands:

```
rf = RegionMember[
   ParametricRegion[{Sin[u], r Sin[2 u]}, {{u, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1}}]];

ParametricPlot[{Sin[u], Sin[2 u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Point[Pick[data, rf[data]]]}]
```

[image: region]

The problem is solved in one line, completely without explicitly forming a list of boundary points.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Strange that we both waited exactly 48 minutes before answering and then did so simultaneously!

Answer (score 9):

Compute the points of a polygon and use any of the methods from [How to check if a 2D point is in a polygon?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9405/121).  I'll use Simon's `inPolyQ2`.

```
g = ParametricPlot[{Sin[u], Sin[2 u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}];
poly = Cases[g, Line[x_] :> x, -1][[1]];
inside = Pick[data, inPolyQ2[poly, ##] & @@@ data];
Show[g, Epilog -> {Red, Point@inside}]
```

[image]

Comment: @Jens Thanks! For what it's worth I think using the adaptive sampling of `ParametricPlot` (as I do here) is superior to uniform sampling of `Table`.  Also, inclusion testing could be faster if `inPolyQ2` were compiled for the specific polygon thereby eliminating significant redundancy.

Comment: You're probably right, but I wanted to be as short as possible - that's what Algohi asked for, right? I guess it depends on whether the plot was considered to be already given or not...

Comment: @Jens In that case you might as well use `ListLinePlot` on `pp`.

Comment: But that would have cost me precious extra seconds...

Answer (score 8):

Another undocumented function (also appeared in the Q/A [How to check...](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9405/121)):

```
p = ParametricPlot[{ Sin[u], Sin[2 u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}];
Show[p, ListPlot@Pick[#, Graphics`Mesh`InPolygonQ[p[[1, 1, 3, 2, 1]], #] & /@ #] &@data]
```

[image]

Comment: for getting the points out of the plot, I think Leonid method might be more portable than depending on [[1,1,3,2,1]] indexing as this might change in future versions. As in `points = Reap[ParametricPlot[{Sin[u], Sin[2 u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{Sin[u], Sin[2 u]}]]][[2, 1]];` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364088/mathematica-how-to-obtain-data-points-plotted-by-plot-command

Comment: @Nasser, this is specific to OP's example, and too specific  to work generally.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a contour integral way of determining which points lie inside a closed curve. It has the advantage that it can be applied to any parametric closed contour.

Define the curve corresponding to the parametric curve `{Sin[u], Sin[2 u]}`.

```
f[u_] := Sin[u] + I Sin[2 u];
```

Define the derivative of the curve.

```
df[u_] = D[f[u], u];
```

Define the contour integral around a pole at `x + I y`.

```
inside[x_, y_] := NIntegrate[df[u]/(f[u] - (x + I y)), {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}] // Chop[#, 10^-6] & // # != 0 & // Quiet;
```

For this particular parametric curve this will give zero when the pole is outside the contour, and `±2 Pi I` when it is inside the contour.

BTW, I tried doing this contour integral with `Integrate` (rather than `NIntegrate`) but the  `ConditionalExpression` produced by `Integrate` was not correct. Is it a bug, or is it just me? I don't know.

Apply the `inside` function to some data.

```
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {200, 2}];
datainside = inside @@@ data;
```

Plot the result.

```
ParametricPlot[{Sin[u], Sin[2 u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi},
  Epilog -> MapThread[{If[#2, Red, Blue], Point[#1]} &, {data, datainside}]]
```

This approach will generalise straightforwardly to more complicated contours.