# How to find if x-y point falls within a closed BSplineCurve

Tags: splines

Here's a simple `Manipulate` with a closed `BSplineCurve`, and a `Locator`.

```
Manipulate[Graphics[
 {BSplineCurve[{{0.5, 0.05}, {1.05, 0.7}, {0.4, 1.5}, 
 {-1.15,0.85}, {-0.75, 0.02}, {-0.93, -1}, {0.2, -1.3}, {1.05, -0.83}},
 SplineClosed -> True]}],{pt, Locator}]
```

Is it possible to detect if the Locator is within the boundary of the curve? So that I can perform some action if it is?

I've found similar things here ([52322](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52322/how-to-find-all-data-points-within-closed-curve)) and here ([17306](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17306/how-can-i-highlight-the-points-lying-between-two-lines-in-a-listplot)), but these are all explicit x-y functions, so not so helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use `RegionMember[]` on a `ParametricRegion[]`, using `BSplineFunction[]` to represent your curve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 With[{f = 
    BSplineFunction[{{0.5, 0.05}, {1.05, 0.7}, {0.4, 1.5}, {-1.15, 
       0.85}, {-0.75, 0.02}, {-0.93, -1}, {0.2, -1.3}, {1.05, -0.83}},
      SplineClosed -> True]},
  reg = Polygon[Table[f[t], {t, 0, 1, 0.01}]];
  rm = RegionMember[reg];
  ];
 Column[{Graphics[{Point[p], EdgeForm[{Red, Thick}], Yellow, reg}, 
    PlotRange -> Table[{-2, 2}, {2}]], 
   Row[{"Region Member: ", rm[p]}]}],
 {{p, {0.5, 0.5}}, Locator}
 ]
```

[image]

**Note**

As @Guesswhoitis. notes in comments region could also be obtained as:

```
Cases[ParametricPlot[(* stuff *)], Line[l_] :> Polygon[l], ∞][[1]]
```

Comment: This is mostly what I had in mind, except that I'd have used `ParametricPlot[]` to construct the shape. (Still, + 1!)

Comment: @J. M. when I originally looked I used ParametricPlot of BSplineFunction...but just thought Polygon would end being cleaner...thanks for upvote :)

Comment: Well, you could still use `Cases[ParametricPlot[(* stuff *)], Line[l_] :> Polygon[l], ∞][[1]]`, of course. :)

Comment: @J. M. yes...I will add to answer :)

Comment: Ah, `RegionMember`. Thanks. That makes it simple.